# How can the mass flow rate in a nozzle be increased in a converging diverging nozzle even after choking condition has taken place?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

If we have a challenge to increase the mass flow rate in a [CD nozzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Laval_nozzle), with additional condition like no structural changes are allowed, and cooling the nozzle is not allowed (inefficient), and you cannot change the medium of flow (to change density or other parameter).

How can we increase the mass flow rate in such a case?